# Is there a tool or a methodology to write XQueries starting from an XSD file?

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery

We know that XQuery is built to write queries over XML files, which are instances of XSD files. I'm looking for a tool or even a methodology, to write an XQuery starting from an XSD file.

Comment: I guess you need to explain a bit more what you mean with "write an XQuery starting from an XSD file". Schema-aware XQuery is possible, see http://www.stylusstudio.com/schema-aware.html for instance, Saxon EE supports that, Altova I think as well, and editors integrating that. I think XmlPrime supports it as well, not sure about the various XQuery data base solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have an XQuery function library that takes an XSD and transforms it to a typeswitch transform XQuery function library with stubbed functions for each element within the Schema.

[tsgen.xqm](https://gist.github.com/lcahlander/9111ce9330f80458dce6eded9b40ebbf)

Here is an example where the transform is running against the XML Schema's XSD.

```
xquery version "3.1";

import module namespace tsgen="http://easymetahub.com/ns/tsgen" at "tsgen.xqm";

declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization"; 
declare option output:method "text";


tsgen:schema(fn:doc('https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd')/xs:schema, map {
'modulePrefix' : 'xsd2json',
       'moduleNamespace' : 'http://easymetahub.com/ns/xsd2json',
       'schemaPrefix' : 'xs',
       'schemaNamespace' : 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
       })
```

Comment: Interesting stuff, I wonder why the library generates code with `xquery version "3.0"` although the generated code uses the XQuery 3.1 `map` type with e.g. `$model as map(*)`. Shouldn't that be `xquery version "3.1"`?

Comment: I invite feedback.  I originally developed it to run in the eXist-db database.  It had the map type in 3.0.  I would also like additional suggestions.

Comment: just a minor comment. whitespaces around `:` inside map constructors are actually not arbitrary because maps can contain namespaced keys or values. So recommendation is `'schemaPrefix': 'xs'`. There is a long ticket about me finding out about this hard way here https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/1725

Comment: I have made the edits so that the generated code is XQuery version "3.1" and eliminated the space before the colon in the documentation.